# Sporadic groups generated by two simple permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Fixing $n\ge 1$, consider the permutation $p$ on $n$ elements whose word representation consists of the even integers ascending up to $n$, followed by the odd integers descending from $n$. Let $q$ be the reverse of $p$.  The permutations are perhaps more easily defined via example: when $n=8$, we have $p=24687531$ and $q=13578642$.

Here's a natural question: What is the group $G$ generated by the permutations $p,q$?

Using GAP, I have computed these groups for $1\le n\le 128$. The answer is *almost* a straightforward one: $A_n$ when $n=0,1\pmod{4}$, and $S_n$ when $n=2,3\pmod{4}$. That is, it will be as large as possible, given the parity of $p$ and $q$.

However, this classification has the following exceptions:

- When $n=2^k$ for $k\ge2$, $G$ is a combination of direct and semidirect products of certain cyclic groups, with an order of $2^k\cdot (k+1)$; I think it is always given by the semidirect product $(C_2)^k\rtimes C_{k+1}$, though this doesn't always match how GAP's `StructureDescription()` function interprets the group. (When $k=2$, this coincides with the expected $A_4$.)
- When $n=6$, $G$ is not $S_6$, but $S_5$.
- When $n=12$, $G$ is not $A_{12}$, but the sporadic simple group $M_{12}$.

I have two questions about these groups and their apparent classification.

- Can we understand how the $n=6$ and $n=12$ sporadic cases work? I suspect at least the $n=6$ case is related somehow to the sporadic outer automorphisms of $S_6$, but I am not quite sure how this connection manifests.
- Can the classification outlined above be proven for all other $n$, if indeed it is true? (If not, can a counterexample be found?)

For convenience, the Sage code used to reach the above conclusions is linked [here](https://pastebin.com/xYTQwNh3), and can be run [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: This group has been studied previously - or rather a closely related group has, namely the group generated by the two perfect shuffles of a deck of $2n$ cards. The structure of the group is exactly as you described. This was proved by Diaconis, Graham and Kantor, which you can find easily by searching for "perfect shuffle group"

Comment: The case $n = 12$ also seems related to the Topsy Turvy puzzle, although only one of the two generators is actually the same as yours.